# How to create a style of word that stands on top of a word on Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles

How to create a style of word that stands on top of a word on Indesign -  like this:

[image: word that stands on top of a word]  [image: Word, Second Word]

But in a way that they would be on the **same line, not a separate paragraph or table cells.**

I use it for word-for-word interpretation in ancient text

Comment: Japanese has a similar practice called '[furigana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furigana)', annotating the pronunciation of lesser-known characters with phonetics. Maybe searching for how that is done will help?

Comment: Interesting question. Can you show how you want the words to be on the same paragraph? Do you mean: `Word foo, Second Word second foo` or `Word, Second Word foo second foo`?

Comment: On the same line? Then a script (a robust one) will be needed...

Comment: @Wolff I meant the following way of writing `Word foo, Second Word second foo`

Comment: @Vinny Okay, but what script will be based? How will he do this job?

Comment: @i.Madar You didn't say how you make the difference between words and "foos". Character style, tag, separator... ?

Comment: @Vinny I think the difference should be a special  character separator, in example percentage character (%)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method for a script which will do what you want.

The goal is a setup like shown below.

[image]

You need a *Main Text Frame* (cyan) which contains the main story. The *Main Text* (red)  is left aligned and used for the punctuation and defining the main leading. Each *Interpreted Word* (blue) with its corresponding *Original Word* (green) below is center aligned inside an auto-sized *Word Container* (magenta) which is anchored inside the *Main Text Frame*.

Initially your text could formatted with *Main Text* and be in the form:

`Word [foo], Second Word [second foo] Third Word [third foo], Fourth Word [fourth foo].`

The script will start searching the text in the *Main Text Frame* from the beginning.

- When a `]` is encountered, the text from the beginning of the search to and including the `]` will be referenced.
- A new *Word Container* text frame will be created.
- The text inside the brackets in the found text followed by a paragraph break will be inserted into the *Word Container* and formatted with *Interpreted Word*.
- The text before the brackets in the found text will be inserted into the *Word Container* and formatted with *Original Word*.
- The *Word Container* will be inserted in the *Main Text Frame* in place of the found text.
- Any punctuation is ignored.
- The search continues until the end of the text has been reached.